# Trigger Django Signal from Different Database other than default db

Tags: django

I have different database other than default.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Customer)
def customer_post_save_task(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("hmm", created)
```

But This only triggers when Customer is created from default db
If Customer is created from another db it does not get invoked.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'mydb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
```

When customer is created in mydb signal doesnot trigger. What can I do?

Comment: did you find the answer if yes please help me .